# Why can't execute multiprocess using member variables of class?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-multiprocessing, python-3.7, spawn

I tested a code using python 3.6 and python 3.7 by 2 cases.

**1 case) using Member variables of class**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
class Foo:
    def do_multiprocessing(self):
        ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
        self.process_1 = ctx.Process(target=self.do_stuff1)
        self.process_2 = ctx.Process(target=self.do_stuff2)

        self.process_1.start()
        self.process_2.start()

    def do_stuff1(self):
        print("Doing 1")

    def do_stuff2(self):
        print("Doing 2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("PYTHON VERSION : ", sys.version)
    foo = Foo()
    foo.do_multiprocessing()
```

Result : When i executed it using python 3.6, working well. However, when i executed it using python 3.7, a error occurred.(TypeError: Can't pickle weakref object)

**2 case) using local variables**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
class Foo:
    def do_multiprocessing(self):
        ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
        process_1 = ctx.Process(target=self.do_stuff1)
        process_2 = ctx.Process(target=self.do_stuff2)

        process_1.start()
        process_2.start()

    def do_stuff1(self):
        print("Doing 1")

    def do_stuff2(self):
        print("Doing 2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("PYTHON VERSION : ", sys.version)
    foo = Foo()
    foo.do_multiprocessing()
```

Result : When i executed it using python 3.6 and python 3.7, working well.

Why can't execute multiprocess using member variables of class? And why can execute multiprocess using local variables?

I can't understand why a code execute.

p.s.) if using mp.get_context('fork'), the code works well using python 3.6 and python 3.7 on case 1.

Answer (score 0):

By passing `self.do_stuff2` to `process_2`, you’re trying to give that process access to the **entirety** of `self` (as an implicit argument), which includes `self.process_1`.  You can see how giving one child process meaningful access to another might be complicated (unless you have the OS replicate the whole (parent) process with `'fork'`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Could you explain more easily?
I have a hard time understanding it.

Comment: An object `x` is reachable from a bound method created from it (`b=x.f`).  Of course it is; otherwise how would calling it (`b()`) provide `self` to `f`?  That means, though, that `x.process_1` is also reachable, so trying to launch `x.do_stuff2` as a child process involves trying to send that child process the value `x.process_1`, which it can't do.